# How to Count Timestamp on Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets

My responses are timestamped as soon as anyone submits a survey. I wanted to count those timestamp monthwise.

URL - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AkpZp6MVqYv1dE5SZjJIODB1WF9nZDR6b1ZJZjFPenc&usp=sharing

**I wanted to find out number of positive responses for a particular question (lets say Q1) for a particular month (lets say May)**

Column G is not founded out based on the timestamp of Q1, I had asked the user the month, but that's not the correct way to do so, so I have stopped asking the user to enter the month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to overcome the fact that the timestamp isn't compatible with googles date format.  No biggie,... luckily it looks like you have a fixed format ie DD/MM/YYYY.  So you can use the LEFT and RIGHT formulas like so `=right(left(a2,5),2)`  This will give you the month in text, ie `05`.

Great.

Now for the harder stuff.  If you have the newer google spreadsheets, you can simply use countifs to the effect of: 
`=countifs(arrayformula(right(left(A$2:A,5),2)),"=05",B$2:B,"=Positive")`

For each month, replace the `"=05"` with the the date number you want.  You could also make a month lookup chart for all months and questions so that you don't have to modify the formula for each month and quesiton.  For this you replace the `"=05"` with `=[cell number containing month number as text]` (NOTE: for making a lookup key, you will have to pay close attention to the fact that you are getting TEXT in the formula above vice a number.  There is a difference and they are not compatible as-is.)

Let's say you don't have the new google spreadsheets.  Then you can use the old `sumproduct()` and `if()`.  Yes, it is old.  See the following:
`=sumproduct(arrayformula(if(right(left(A$2:A,5),2)="05",1,0)),arrayformula(if(B$2:B="Positive",1,0)))`

Note in both of these, you need to use arrayformula to convert the column with the timestamp into something useable.  If you want to make this part easier by removing the parseing functions (`LEFT()` and `RIGHT()`) you need to change the timestamp format to be MM/DD/YYYY.  Then you can plug in the the `MONTH(DATE)` formula and it will be done.

Then make a master sheet like so (note my formula has a "`'`" in it to make it visible for purposes of demonstration, you should remove it.):
[image]
Careful inspection might note that the count is wrong. That is because when I imported your timestamps, times like "02/06/2014 ..." were interpreted to mean "February 06" because of google's auto-formatting.  In your sheet you will get the correct count using this formula, because of the way your timestamp is auto-populated.

HINT: To make the month a text you need to enter `="05"` in the Month column

Please let me know how you make out.

Comment: Hey, when I entered your code I am facing one issue.. here is the URL of the survey Google Form whose responses are automatically updated in Google Spreadsheets http://www.getcsr.com

As soon as a new response is submitted, that code which you gave is not working.. u can have a look. It is displaying blank

Comment: I have around 90 responses..Whats happening is when i added this =right(left(a2,5),2) and dragged it down till 100 it showed me all 90. but as soon as a new responses come it, the cells are getting shifted down and the 91 row is blank and 92-101 is filled up with the command added on the top

Comment: I see what you tried to do.  The bit about right(left(a...)) is just to show how to get the month into something you can use.  Instead of trying to break it out directly you should use `arrayformula()`. But to accomplish, what looks to be, your ultimate goal, make a master sheet that will summarize the data.  I've updated the answer showing what I am talking about.

Comment: @user51818 Look up the following entry where I explained a little about arrayformula().  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24075179/google-sheets-using-arrayformula-to-countif-depending-on-date-in-range/24089021#24089021)

Comment: I am not able to understand what you are trying to convey. based on the information provided by you.. I used the code given by you for the old spreadsheet format.. and it worked.. for my project, i needed only positive and negative responses.. {Check out my Sheet 2).. So it worked..

Comment: Only issue is its semi automatic.. is there any way through which I can make the spreadsheet to populate months automatically.. Like in Sheet 2, I manually added months May, June July, August.. is there any way through which i can detect from my responses that suppose after august if any responses comes like in Sep, it should automatically detect it and run all the formulas which i have made?

Thanks for your help..

Comment: @user51818, Yes! Absolutely!  This is doable for sure.  You should create a separate question for that, though.  Based off of your question, the formulas I provided answer this question.  The answer here will be very long, you are looking at creating a separate script.  Trust me, very do able.  Your quesiton should look like, how do I automatically detect, and parse a string to fill in a cell with the result.  You will have to provide a lot of detail though.  There are a lot of quesitons here on how this should be implemented.  Mark this question answered and start a new one.